# My coffeescript for jquery-ui-rails is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, coffeescript

I am using jquery-ui-rails gem package for datepicker in my rails. but it isn't working.
Here is my Gemfile

```
group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

    # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'jquery-ui-rails' # For use of datepicker 
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

Here is my application.js file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require tree .
```

Here is my appplication.css file

```
*= require jquery.ui.datepicker
 *= require_self 
 *= require tree .
```

This is my home.html.erb file

```
<%= text_field_tag "created_at"%>
```

This one is my home.js.coffee file

```
jQuery -> $("#created_at").datepicker()
```

This give produce error like this

```
TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

return $("#created_at").datepicker();
```

Whenever I click in return $("#created_at").datepicker(); this will produce this code

```
(function() {
jQuery(function() {
return $("#created_at").datepicker();
});
}).call(this);
```

I think my coffeescrip is correct. But why it is giving this code return $("#created_at").datepicker(); in home.js file. Does any one have idea about it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this gem package is not working so I call jquery ui in my application.htm.erb like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PV-NEC</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```